# Python - extracting elements from list

Tags: python, list

I've got different product titles from which I want to extract amount of product, for example:

```
title = "Prażynki Roasty Ribs Lorenz, 45 g BBQ Hot&Spicy"

title = "Precelki Chrupkie Paluszki słone ; 49 + Chrupiące kulki gratis  Lajkonik, 130-200 g"
```

I can convert it to a list by title.split(" "). What is easy way to extract amount (i.e. "45 g" in first example, "130-200 g" in second one) and remove it from the title at once? I mean one method which is flexible enough to handle amounts placed in different positions of the title (one time in the middle, another time at the end etc.)

The result should look like:

```
name = "Prażynki Roasty Ribs Lorenz, BBQ Hot&Spicy"
amount = "45 g"

name = "Precelki Chrupkie Paluszki słone ; 49 + Chrupiące kulki gratis  Lajkonik"
amount = "130-200 g"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could locate the index of the 'grams' unit and then work with that. The words immediately preceding the unit is part of the amount (error checking omitted, you should make up your mind on what to do if there is no `g` in the input string, or if it's the first word in the input string, or if there is more than one `g`).

```
def f(s):
    words = s.split()
    unitIdx = words.index('g')
    name = words[:unitIdx - 1] + words[unitIdx + 1:]
    amount = words[unitIdx - 1] + ' ' + words[unitIdx]
    return ' '.join(name), amount

# Prints ('Prazynki Roasty Ribs Lorenz, BBQ Hot&Spicy', '45 g')
print f("Prazynki Roasty Ribs Lorenz, 45 g BBQ Hot&Spicy")

# Prints ('Precelki Chrupkie Paluszki stone ; 49 + Chrupiqce kulki gratis Lajkonik,', '130-200 g')
print f("Precelki Chrupkie Paluszki stone ; 49 + Chrupiqce kulki gratis Lajkonik, 130-200 g")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex such that:

```
re.search(r"\b(\d+(?:\-\d+)?) g\b", title)
```